# How to fix Windows Media Player not selecting correct audio track when playing an MP4 file?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, windows-media-player, mp4

Windows Media Player does not play back the correct audio track when one is selected from the Audio menu.

This is for MP4 files with multiple audio tracks (around 32-64).

VLC does the correct thing in all cases with the same files.

Is this a known issue or is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe the codec of the selected track is not supported by WMP? VLC is known to support many codecs, which is (or at least was) far from the case of WMP.

Comment: It can play audio tracks, just not the right ones.  I'm using MP4+AAC which is probably the most common format.

Comment: [This post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bfc6a05a-bcf8-4b4e-8edb-9cdd20e221ff/wmp-12-plays-the-wrong-audio-track-by-default-on-mp4-files?forum=w7itpromedia) (from 2012!) says that it only works correctly in full-screen mode.